# Merge multiple lines into one line using Informatica

Tags: informatica

I have a `.txt` file that contains multiple lines separated by `~`.

The input below is just an example - the actual file will have many lines which will vary every time.

```
abcdefgh~
asdfghjkliuy~
qwertyuiopasdfgh~
..........
```

Every line ends with `~`, and I would like to merge all the lines into one.

Desired output:

```
abcdefgh~asdfghjkliuy~qwertyuiopasdfgh~..................................
```

How can I merge all the lines into one line using Informatica and write the result to a `.txt` file?

Answer (score 1):

This is a concat multiple row to a column problem. Now, if you have a key on which you want to concat, it will make life easy else your concat string will be very long.
so, here are steps.

1. Sort the data based on key. if you dont have one ignore the step.
2. Create an expression transformation and create below ports.

```
in_key
in_data
v_data = IIF( prev_key <> in_key,in_data, v_data || in_data)
prev_data = in_data
prev_key = in_key
out_key = in_key
out_data = v_data
```

if you do not have key,

```
in_data
v_data =v_data || in_data
prev_data = in_data 
out_data = v_data
```

Link out_key and out_data to next agg.  Pls note, out_data column and v_data column should be data type `string` so that they can handle large concatenated string.

3. Attach an aggregator after this expression. Group by key if you have key. Create one output port like below.

```
out_data = MAX(data)
```

- Link this field to target.